# Problems with start MariaDb / MySQL on Fedora 27 / 28

Tags: mysql, mariadb, fedora

I'm trying just install mysql/mariadb on fedora 28 but after install it isn't starting server.

When I typed *systemctl start mariadb.service* got this message :

*Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.*

Analysing journal see these error messages :

```
*2018-09-03  8:01:20 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
set 03 08:01:20 localhost.localdomain 
mysqld[4944]: 2018-09-03  8:01:20 0 [ERROR] Recovery failed! You must enable all engines that were enabled at t>
set 03 08:01:20 localhost.localdomain 
mysqld[4944]: 2018-09-03  8:01:20 0 [ERROR] Crash recovery failed. Either correct the problem (if it's, for exa>
set 03 08:01:20 localhost.localdomain 
mysqld[4944]: 2018-09-03  8:01:20 0 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
set 03 08:01:20 localhost.localdomain 
mysqld[4944]: 2018-09-03  8:01:20 0 [ERROR] Aborting*
```

Have sombody a light to put over this dark problem ?

Comment: Edit you post and put output of `systemctl status mariadb.service`

Answer (score 1):

It possibly zero byte appear on `tc.log` . Delete or r and restart the process should works.

```
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/tc.log /var/lib/mysql/tc.log.bak
systemctl restart mariadb.service
```

Ref :

1. https://fransdejonge.com/2018/02/mariadb-fix-cant-init-tc-log-error/
2. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=206379